# error calling member function of alleged non-object in Codeigniter controller

Tags: php, codeigniter-2

I get the error

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function retrieve_products() on a non-object
```

The controller is:

```
<?php   
class Cart extends CI_Controller { // Our Cart class extends the Controller class  

   public function _construct()  
   {  
       parent::_construct(); // We define the the Controller class is the parent.  
       $this->load->model('Cart_model'); // Load our cart model for our entire class  
   }

   function index()  
   {  
      $data['products'] = $this->cart_model->retrieve_products(); // Retrieve an array with all products  
   }
}
```

The model is:

```
<?php   
class Cart_model extends CI_Model {

    function retrieve_products(){  
        $query = $this->db->get('products'); // Select the table products  
        return $query->result_array(); // Return the results in a array.
    }             
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I want to say that your call

```
$data['products'] = $this->cart_model->retrieve_products();
```

Should be:

```
$data['products'] = $this->Cart_model->retrieve_products();
```

Ie: uppercase "C" in cart_model

Comment: well, already tried that but shows the same problem. Somewhere, I found that when there is no entries in a database table (in this case 'products'), it shows that error but i do have some entries.

Comment: Is the database library present and loaded?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe we're using different versions (I have 1.7.2), but to declare a model, `CI_` does not appear.  My working code has the equivalent of:

```
class Cart_model extends Model
```

Also, the class should capitalized:

```
$this->Cart_model->retrieve_products();
```

(instead of)

```
$this->cart_model->retrieve_products();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think its your typo error you have spelled construct function as `_construct` rather than `__construct` thats why codeigniter considers it as a function rather than a class constructor and model loading is limited to only that function.